# Trying to plot 2 charts side-by-side, but one of them always comes out empty

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have two plots that I generated from my data:

[image] [image]

Here the second plot shows the distribution of results from the first one.

What I want is to plot them side-by-side so you could see both the data and the distribution on the same plot. And I want plots to share y-axis as well.

I tried to do the following:

```py
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(40, 15), sharey=True)
ax1 = sns.lineplot(plotting_df.index, plotting_df.error, color=('#e65400'), lw=2, label='random forest residual error')
ax1 = sns.lineplot(plotting_df.index, plotting_df.val, color=('#9b9b9b'), lw=1, label='current model residual error')
ax1 = sns.lineplot(plotting_df.index, 0, color=('#2293e3'), lw=1)
ax1.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax1.set_ylabel('Residual Fe bias', fontsize=16)
ax1.set_title('Models residual error comparison', fontsize=20, fontweight='bold')
sns.despine(ax=ax1, top=True, bottom=True, right=True)

ax2 = sns.distplot(results_df.error, hist=True, color=('#e65400'), bins=81,
                   label='Random forest model', vertical=True)
ax2 = sns.distplot(plotting_df.val, hist=True, color=('#9b9b9b'),
                   bins=81, label='Rolling averages model', vertical=True)
ax2.set_title('Error distribution comparison between models', fontsize=20, fontweight='bold')   
sns.despine(ax=ax2, top=True, right=True)

fig.savefig("blabla.png", format='png')
```

But when I do run it I get strange results - the first chart is in the second column, whereas I wanted it on the left and the second chart is completely blank. Not sure what I did wrong here.

[image]

Comment: You need to pass the axis instance to your seaborn commands explicitly (`sns.lineplot(...., ax=ax1)`, etc.). Otherwise, seaborn will get (and then return) the current axis, which is the last axis created. At the moment, your first `lineplot` call grabs the **second** axis, `ax2`, and then you create another reference to `ax2` by overwriting `ax1`. As a result, you are only doing stuff to `ax2` with all of your commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [`lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) and [`distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) accept a matplotlib axes object as an argument, which tells it which axes to plot onto. If no axes is passed into it, then the plot is placed onto the current axes.

You create a figure and 2 axes using :

`fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(40, 15), sharey=True)`

Therefore, `ax2` will be the current axes. So your distplot is being plotted on top of your lineplot, both in `ax2`.

You need to pass the axes into the seaborn plotting functions.

```
sns.lineplot(..., ax=ax1)
sns.distplot(..., ax=ax2)
```